# Used Disk Utility to resize Macintosh HD partition on Boot Camp-enabled machine - now can't boot Windows

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I have a late-2013 MacBook Pro running the latest Mac OS Sierra (updated this afternoon). I have Windows 10 installed on a Boot Camp partition.

I decided to decrease the size of the Mac OS partition as I'm running low on space in the Boot Camp partition. So I used Disk Utility to shrink the Mac OS partition, then formatted the unused space as FAT32.

There were no reported problems.

I then restarted the MacBook. It's set to boot directly into Windows, but when I restarted all I got was a blank screen. I waited... but got nothing.

So I forced the MacBook off (holding the power button) and restarted again, this time holding `⌥`: I got to the partition selection screen, from where I clicked on "Windows". It froze. The pointer becomes unresponsive. Again, nothing.

I can still start up and select to boot into Mac OS but I can do nothing with the partition from where I do my job, leaving me in a bit of a panic.

In Disk Utility, I've clicked on the top-level disk, "Apple SSD", and selected "Repair", and after ~2 seconds it said something like "OK". I don't have an option to click on "Repair" when I click on any of the partitions.

I haven't used any third-party software, using *only* Disk Utility for its own purpose, and haven't touched the Windows partition.

*Please*, can someone tell me how to get my Windows partition booting once again.

I've since removed the empty partition which I had cerated, merging it back into the Macintosh HD partition.

Here is the output from running `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):  
   #:     TYPE NAME                       SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     GUID_partition_scheme           *500.3 GB  disk0  
   1:     EFI EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1  
   2:     Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD  249.4 GB   disk0s2  
   3:     Apple_Boot Recovery HD          650.0 MB   disk0s3                                            
   4:     Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP   249.6 GB   disk0s4  
   5:     Windows Recovery                471.9 MB   disk0s5  

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):  
   #:     TYPE NAME                       SIZE       IDENTIFIER  
   0:     Apple_HFS Macintosh HD          +249.0 GB  disk1  
          Logical Volume on disk0s2  
          EAD39943-E2B3-41BA-94C4-319E53324ECD  
          Unencrypted
```

Comment: *Golden Rule* - don't ever touch Boot Camp other than with Boot Camp Assistant. There are a couple of guys on here [...in the world!...] who have the skill to fix this. I hope they pick up your case. Wish you luck.

Comment: Please tell us you had a full backup before you started ....

Comment: Yes, I have backups of both OSs. But I'm a freelancer/contractor and this hiccup means I can't work. It'll take at least a full day to get everything back to where I was so I'm desperately hoping someone can tell me how to set that partition as bootable once again.

Comment: That at least is a good position to be in with the backups - hope you get a solution